# How are params passed from the New to Create action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, model-view-controller, controller

I understand that the `new` action for a rails form normally instantiates a model and provides a view with inputs for permitted params.

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end
```

What I don't get is how that same information submitted by the user is carried over to `Post.new` method inside the `create` action:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  ...
end
```

How does rails channel these params to `create` despite the page refresh that occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two requests with each other. When you hit the `new` action, a view that contains your `form` gets rendered. As it gets rendered, the `new` action finishes, and now the `new` action has nothing to do with `create` action.

You need `new` action to create a `form` through `form_for` method in which you actually pass an object, in your case `@post`.

The `create` action is independent, and `params` it receives, they have nothing to do with `new` method, those `params` are received through `form` rendered in the new.html.erb file of views.

You can also invoke the `create` method in your controller by sending the data through AJAX or even using cURL or POSTMAN - a chrome extension.

And as you asked:

> How does rails channel these params to create despite the page refresh that occurs?

Rails doesn't channel these `params`, Rails run at back-end, Rails just receives those `params`. They are sent through an HTML form, and as I said earlier there are other ways to send `params` as well.

Comment: If this is the case why isn't it `Post.create(post_params)` vs Post.new(`post_params)`?

Comment: In `def create` it should be `Post.create post_params` instead of `Post.new`, in most simple cases that is. `Post.create ...` will save the object and make a SQL call to the database to insert the new record in the `posts` table. `Post.new ...` will just create a new object and load it with the specified params. You'd have to call `@post.save` on that item to save it to the database.

Comment: Because you aren't receiving in `params` in your new method, neither you should. Do remember that `new` method and `create` method are independent. You just do `Post.new` in your `new` method so that you could get `@post` object, and then you pass `@post` to your view and send it to `form_for` - this way `form_for` knows that which kind of object you are talking about, and what attributes should it possess.

Comment: You can even remove `Post.new` for your `new` method, and in your view file: new.html.erb, you can past the raw HTML for the form, and it will work perfectly.

Comment: @DerProgrammer You can't say that **it should be `Post.create post_params`**. It is up to us. Sometimes, we just want to `build` an object, and want to save it latter, therefore we do `Post.new`.

Comment: @DerProgrammer I assume that the `new` method is used in the event that an instance runs into something like a validation error. That way it isn't immediately written into the db if you were to use the `create` method instead?

Comment: @CarlEdwards You are kind of right, but even with `create` method, if attributes are invalid, `create` method doesn't invoke any db function. An object will only be written to database if it is valid irrespective of you persist it through `save` or `create`.

Comment: Exactly what Arslan said regarding validations. `#new` is used more often if you want to create a new instance of an object but you are going to modify it before you save it to the database. This way you are only making a single call (one `INSERT` statement) to the database instead of an `INSERT` and then an `UPDATE` sql call, which would effectively double the stress you are putting on the database if you are creating/modifying a large number of objects.